# When I ran my for loop, I got this message: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" How do I make my arguments compatible?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a For loop to iterate over a list, for one parameter in a multi-parameter mathematical function I have defined.  I got an error message stating basically that I can't add list elements to integers.
I tried changing the list to a tuple, -got a similar error message.  I then tried converting the integer arguments to tuples, -didn't work.  I tried converting the iterated elements into integers with the int()function, -didn't work.

```py
c = (int(clkm))
dc = (int(dclkm))

tts = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

def odp(x, y = dae):
   return ((x+(dc*tts))*y)*k*2*s4h*dac/kmo  # remaining arguments are previously defined integers

a = c
for wt in range(len(tts)):
    do3t = odp(a)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For help with a debugging problem, please include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself, the desired result/behavior and the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) module to make it possible to add an array and a number, by converting your list to a  `numpy.array`

```py
import numpy as np

c = (int(clkm))
dc = (int(dclkm))

tts = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30])

def odp(x, y = dae):
   return ((x+(dc*tts))*y)*k*2*s4h*dac/kmo  # remaining arguments are previously defined integers

a = c
for wt in range(len(tts)):
    do3t = odp(a)
```